# React - “localStorage is not defined” error showing

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, meta-tags, server-side-rendering

I am trying to make my website SEO friendly with meta tags.
I am implementing server-side rendering in my application. After this, I am getting the following error:

> ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined.

Please help how to resolve it.

My `package.json`:

```
{


 "main": "server.js",
 "scripts": {
  "start-dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack -w & NODE_ENV=development node server.js",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.18.0",
  "express": "^4.15.3",
  "firebase": "^4.12.1",
  "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
  "react": "^16.2.0",
  "react-adsense": "0.0.5",
  "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
  "react-facebook-login": "^4.0.1",
  "react-google-login": "^3.2.1",
  "react-meta-tags": "^0.3.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
  "react-router-match-as-promised": "^1.0.5",
  "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
  "react-share": "^2.1.1",
  "react-slick": "^0.22.3"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
  "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
  "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
  "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
  "webpack": "^3.1.0",
  "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
 }
}
```

Meta Tags commonly used in all pages.
Home.js

```
<code>
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axinst from '../common';
import {TabBox,TabBox2,TabBox3} from '../common/tabbox';
import Ads  from '../common/ads';
import SubscribeFrm from '../common/subscribefrm';
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';
import AdSense from 'react-adsense';
import Loader from '../common/loader';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    header:[],
    otherSports:[],
    wizztalk:[],
    sports:[],
    isProgress:'',
    activeCat: '',
    metaTitle:'',
    metaDesc:'',
    metaKey:''
  }

  componentDidMount(){


    // axinst.get('/home')
    this.setState({isProgress:true});
    axinst.get('/home').then(response => {
      this.setState({isProgress:false});
      const header = response.data.data.Header;
      const sports = response.data.data.Sports;
      const otherSports = response.data.data.OtherSports;
      const wizztalk = response.data.data.Wizztalk;
      const metaTitle = response.data.data.metaTitle;
      const metaDesc = response.data.data.metaDesc;
      const metaKey = response.data.data.metaKeyword;
      this.setState({header});
      this.setState({sports});
      this.setState({otherSports})
      this.setState({wizztalk});
      this.setState({metaTitle});
      this.setState({metaDesc});
      this.setState({metaKey});
    }).catch(function (error) {
      // console.log(error);
      // console.log('error');
    });
  }

  render() {
    const hD = this.state.header;
    const sport = this.state.sports;
    return (
    <div id="maincontent">
        <MetaTags>
          <title>{this.state.metaTitle}</title>
          <meta name="title" content={this.state.metaTitle} />
          <meta name="keywords" content={this.state.metaKeyword} />
          <meta name="description" content={this.state.metaDesc} />
          <meta name="og:description" content={this.state.metaDesc} />
          <meta name="og:title" content={this.state.metaTitle} />
          <meta name="og:image" content={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +"/images/logo.png"}/>
        </MetaTags>
</code>
```

Comment: so you're trying to using `localStorage` on server side, right?

Comment: Please check my package.json file and let me know what else you need to see

Comment: yes, Alex you are right.

Answer (score 90):

When you're rendering on the server, you do not have a browser and thus you do not have access to all the APIs that the browser provides, including [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

In JavaScript code that is running both on the server and on the client (browser), it is common practice to guard against with an `if` clause that checks if [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window) is defined. “Window” is the root object provided by the browser for all the APIs that are provided by the browser.

Example:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('we are running on the client')
} else {
    console.log('we are running on the server');
}
```

In your case, you want to put your call to `localStorage` in such an `if` clause, for example:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
}
```

Comment: The code in your question does not use localStorage anywhere. Perhaps it is used in one of the packages you're importing, possibly *react-adsense*. But you didn't include the part where you actually use that, so I cannot help you further.

Comment: can you please guide me how to use localstorage in my application. or send any useful link if you have any.

Comment: I already did, or tried to: wherever you use local storage, check if it's actually available with an if clause like I showed in my code examples

Comment: I have used your code, but still getting same error.

Comment: As @PatrickHund said you might want to check the code/docs of your dependencies to check which package is using `localStorage` and replace it with a _SSR friendly_ package

Answer (score 17):

This oneliner did it for me:

```
const checkout = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? localStorage.getItem('checkout') : null
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add [a polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localstorage-polyfill) to your app. I.e. somewhere in your `index.js`:

```
if (!window) {
    require('localstorage-polyfill');
}
```

Comment: After using this code my whole code is break. 
---------------------
Following error is coming.

Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`?

Comment: It's not clear how it could be linked, however yes, react uses `className` attribute instead of `class`.

Comment: I have used this package for metatags.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-meta-tags. i want to make it seo friendly.

Comment: it's already different issue, so I'm assuming the one you asked for help already fixed. For the last issue you've asked - just replace `class` with `className`, it should help. However, I'd note that moving everything to server side rendering - is not a simple task, you'll probably faced with other issues as well. I'd suggest you to ask new specific questions for that (of course if they hasn't been asked before). I don't think somebody here can fix everything in your app in one answer.

Answer (score 2):

On Component you can use useEffect hook for waiting the full page load.

```
    useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.getItem('key');
    }, [input]);
```

And for hooks or functions you can use if condition to check window is loaded or not like this -

```
    if(window !== 'undefined'){ 
      localStorage.getItem('key')
    }
```

Comment: This is correct. `useEffct` will load only if the client component is rendered, so for the best practices, we get `localStorage` in the `useEffect` and use `useState` to store the storage values.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used a `useEffect` to wait for the page to load before using localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more reliable approach if the component logic absolutely depends on the value of `lsVar` to conditionally render something.

```
    const Component = () => {
        if (typeof window === "undefined") return null;

        const lsVar = localStorage.getItem("lsVar");

        // component logic
        
        return (<></>);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with NextJs while checking the query param values for session creation.

***The best working solution was :***

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('Currently on Client side')
} else {
    console.log('Currently on Server Side');
}
```

Inside of the first check (Client side), simply put all the code to handle localStorage.
This works for me fine.