# How to init the store with data from the localstorage?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage, vuex

I an learning Vue (3) and vuex.

I have this store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        user: null
      },
    
      mutations: {
        setUserData (state, userData) {
          state.user = userData
          console.log('userData')
          console.log(userData)
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userData))
          axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${userData.access_token}`
        },
    
        clearUserData () {
          localStorage.removeItem('user')
          location.reload()
        }
      },
    
      actions: {
        login ({ commit }, credentials) {
          return axios
            .post('/login', credentials)
            .then(({ data }) => {
              commit('setUserData', data)
            })
        },
    
        logout ({ commit }) {
          commit('clearUserData')
        }
      },
    
      getters: {
        isLogged: state => !!state.user,
        user: state => state.user
      },
```

And in a component, I want to get the user connected like this:

```
<script>

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      user: 'user'
    })
  },

  data () {
    return {
      stores: [],
      loading: false
    }
  },

  created () {
    console.log('toto')
    console.log(this.user.id)
    this.getStores()
  },
```

The first time the user logs in, it works fine: I can see the user.id in the console.

But when I refresh the page (and the user is connected), the user.id is undefined.

My question is: how to put the user in the store if the localstorage contains the user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can load the initial state value directly from `localStorage`:

```js
state: {
   user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
},
```

Since you used `JSON.stringify` when setting, use `JSON.parse` when getting.

Comment: Does this then JSON parse the local storage from disk every single time you access the state? Or is that just the initial value?

Comment: @partofthething - Just the initial value.  If you want to change the storage, do it in the mutation that changes the state (or in an action that calls that mutation).

Comment: This does not work for me, it says 'localStorage is not defined' when i try to init the store state like you suggested.

Comment: @Luckytechy It's part of the Window API so should always be defined.  Maybe you're running the code on the server side.  See this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474208/react-localstorage-is-not-defined-error-showing

Answer (score 3):

A more generic solution could be to use a plugin that persists the entire state to local storage, that way you don't have to deal with individual values and your whole application is still available when a user hits refresh:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist

If you want more granular control and at the same time the ability to store more complex data type than strings, have a look at localForage:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/localforage

Comment: Why does the user data become undefined in the first place, isn't it supposed to persist across refresh. Is it a vuex  thing ?

Comment: @YemiKudaisi That's normal behaviour for browsers, when you close a tab the data is gone. The only way to prevent that is by storing the state locally and retrieving it when revisiting the same website again. Vuex maintains the state centrally in a session, so that when you go to different pages, you can still access it. But that just works while you are effectively still in the app, it doesn't help when you leave the app and come back.