# Issue: window, document, local storage undefined in node modules during server side rendering using react and express js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, seo, server-side-rendering

I have tried to implement SSR in react js using express js. While we render the client page from server file it throwing browser level object not supported/undefined error in node modules.

If the window/document/localstorage is undefined in application file then can able to solve the issue making some conditions as recommended in this link [React - “localStorage is not defined” error showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474208/react-localstorage-is-not-defined-error-showing)
but the error occurred in node modules.

Here I have attached link for the reference for browser level object only working on client side rendering.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined#:~:text=The%20short%20answer%20is%20don,are%20not%20available%20in%20node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined#:%7E:text=The%20short%20answer%20is%20don,are%20not%20available%20in%20node).

My application is,
React: ^16.12.0 (Created by using create-react-app, build done by using react-scripts command)
Node: v14.17.1
Express: ^4.17.3

Screenshot for reference:
[document undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09GbS.png)