# NEXT.JS - LocalStorage reverts value to original instead of saving on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When you first run the component, it should display "1", and on button click, append it by 3, which it does. Value inside localstorage also changes, but when i reload the page, localstorage changes again to 1... what am i missing?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function Test() {
    
    const [testNum, setTestNum] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        const data = window.localStorage.getItem("MY_TEST_ITEM");
        setTestNum(JSON.parse(data));
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.localStorage.setItem("MY_TEST_ITEM", JSON.stringify(testNum))
    }, [testNum]);

    

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{testNum}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => { setTestNum(testNum + 3) }}>Add</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Test
```

Comment: `useEffect` always runs on initial render and if there are dependencies also runs everytime they change. In your case you don't want to run initially, but only when `testNum` changes. You can't control this with the useEffect alone, you must create a condition check inside. But I would say a better solution would be to set `localStorage` directly in your `onClick` event instead of setting af state and rely on `useEffect` to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are saying give "**testNum**" the value *1* on every page refresh, that means your local storage will be always updated to the initial value on the refresh which is *1*.
So the solution is very obvious, all what you need to do is change the initial state value which should be the localStorage value not the hard coded value.
[image]

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
const [testNum, setTestNum] = useState(null)
const intialValue = 1

useEffect(() => {
    const localStorageValue = window.localStorage.getItem("YOUR_ITEM_KEY") || intialValue
    setTestNum(Number(localStorageValue))
    setLoading(false)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    testNum !== null && window.localStorage.setItem("YOUR_ITEM_KEY", testNum)
}, [testNum])

if(loading) return <div>Loading ...</div>
return(
    <>
        <div>testNum: {testNum}</div>
        <button onClick={e => setTestNum(testNum + 3)}>increment testNum by 3</button>
    </>
)
```

You can also use the **useMemo** hook to avoid any unnecessary re-renders

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to work, I still get 1 on refresh...

Comment: use the code I sent you + the useEffect that updates the localStorage on every testNum change

Comment: I tried that, still nothing happens... I also tried editing code like this: setTestNum(JSON.parse(localStorageValue) - also no luck

Comment: I tested the code on my machine, please retry with the new code above, it will work now

Answer (score 1):

try this instead :

```
const [testNum, setTestNum] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem("MY_TEST_ITEM") === null ? 1 : window.localStorage.getItem("MY_TEST_ITEM"));
```

Comment: Then I get "ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Comment: how about using "localStorage.getItem" without "window."

Comment: Then I get "ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined"

Comment: are you using nextjs?

Comment: const mylocalstorage = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? localStorage.getItem('MY_TEST_ITEM') : null
    const [testNum, setTestNum] = useState(mylocalstorage === null ? 1 : mylocalstorage);

Comment: yes, I do... do I need to do something differently then?

Comment: next js try to render the page on server so there is no local storage until you make sure your app is delivered to the client.

Comment: also this link may be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474208/react-localstorage-is-not-defined-error-showing

Comment: Up vote as this did answer the original question and spot important missing details.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you reload your page your state refreshes.

You have testNum set to 1 so every render it will be set to that.

```
const [testNum, setTestNum] = useState(1);
```

Then you have these useEffects running at the same time

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("MY_TEST_ITEM");
    setTestNum(JSON.parse(data));
}, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("MY_TEST_ITEM", JSON.stringify(testNum))
}, [testNum]);
```

The second useEffect will render before the first one, thus setting the localStorage to 1.

UseEffect is actually not needed in this case.
Try this;

```
const storageValue = window.localStorage.getItem("MY_TEST_ITEM";
const [testNum, setTestNum] = useState(storageValue ?? 0 );

updateLocalStorageFunc(value){
   setTestNum(value)
   window.localStorage.setItem("MY_TEST_ITEM", JSON.stringify(testNum))
}
    


return (    
<div>
    <h1>{testNum}</h1>
    <button onClick={() => { updateLocalStorageFunc(testNum + 3) }   
</div>)
```